# Insert firebase values into a class containing an array

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure in my firebase:

```
[
   {
      "numero":1
   },
   {
      "cpfProprietario":11122233344,
      "moradores":{
         "1112121212":{
            "cpf":"323232",
            "nome":"teste",
            "uid":"dfdsifnds",
            "urlFoto":"/assets/ic_account.svg"
         },
         "11122233344":{
            "cpf":"11122233344",
            "nome":"Maria",
            "uid":"X59CZYkqDAYRIRzHt6leWuCDOzD3",
            "urlFoto":"/assets/ic_account.svg"
         }
      },
      "numero":2
   },
   {
      "numero":3
   }
]
```

The only attribute that I always contain is the `numero`.

I need to save these values into an array of this class:

```
export class Lote {
  public numero: number;
  public cpfProprietario: string;
  public moradores: MyMorador[] = [];

  addMorador(cpf: string, uid: string, nome: string, urlFoto: string) {
    this.moradores.push(new MyMorador(cpf, uid, nome, urlFoto));
  }
}

class MyMorador {
  cpf: string;
  uid: string;
  nome: string;
  urlFoto: string;

  constructor(cpf: string, uid: string, nome: string, urlFoto: string) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
    this.uid = uid;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.urlFoto = urlFoto;
  }
}
```

From what I've noticed, when adding value to the `moradores`, for some reason it does not include it as an `array[]`, , but as an `object{}`

This is part of the code that receives the values:

```
private lotes: Lote[] = [];
private ref: Observable<Lote[]>;
ref.forEach(value => {
        this.lotes = value;
      });
```

This is the error of angular when I try to make a `*ngFor` in `moradores`

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of
>   type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

Comment: This part is ok. I did not put all the code because I do not think it important.
I get the lots. only that morador values come as an object and not as list as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem.

`moradores` was coming as an `Object`, so I just went through the batch `array` and used the function of es6 `Object.values()` and convert to `array`.

I do not know if using `try` like I did is a good practice, but it solved my problem, because sometimes the `moradores` can be undefined or null.

```
ref.forEach(value => {
  this.lotes = value;
  for (const lote of this.lotes) {
    try {
      lote.moradores = Object.values(lote.moradores);
    } catch (err) { }
  }
});
```